# What is this evergreen houseplant?

Tags: houseplants, indoors

[image: this is a evergreen indoor plant]

I have a house plant which has green leaves in the summer and the leaves turn pink and white at the tips in the autumn to spring. When cut at the tip it sprouts another growing shoot from the next leaf node.

Comment: More information or preferably a photograph please. If you can't manage a photo, then how tall and wide is it, is it a climber, a flowering plant, a small evergreen, etc...

Comment: hi here is a close up of the evergreen indoor plant I am trying to identify

Comment: I don't know it's name, but I do know that stick-insects love it. :)

Answer (score 2):

It certainly seems to be a Tradescantia, specifically T. fluminensis; some varieties have leaves striped longitudinally with varying degrees of pink, or have the bottom halves pink. Most likely cultivar name is Tradescantia fluminensis 'Maiden's Blush' - if you increase its light levels, you might find you get more half pink or all pink leaves, but it doesn't like direct sun in high summer.

Answer (score 1):

That is [spiderwort, *Tradescantia* 'Blushing Bride'](http://www.missouribotanicalgarden.org/PlantFinder/PlantFinderDetails.aspx?kempercode=b958). When grown outdoors in zones 4-9, this plant will produce small white flowers from late spring into summer. The best variegation comes with the fastest growth, so during the cooler temps in spring and fall, they really show. If the plant becomes leggy or loses it's color, you can cut it back almost to the base. The new growth will have improved coloration, especially in higher light levels, as Bamboo mentioned. Grown indoors, this will be less showy, but still be a low maintenance plant.

Below are some pics. The light colored plant with the pale variegation was grown in a lower light level.
[image] 
[image]
[image]